# Change permalink rule if category is called "uncategorized"

Tags: permalinks, urls

My current permalink looks like this

```
/%category%/%postname%
```

Basically I want something like this:

If the category of the post is called "Uncategorized" then change the permalink rule from 
`"/%category%/%postname%"`

to

```
"/%postname%"
```

For all other categories leave it as `/%category%/%postname%`

How can I accomplish this?